# Call an URL and send parameters as POST using PHP

Tags: php, xml, rest, jsonp

I know this is maybe a very dummy question, but I'm facing a requirement with PHP, I've made some very simple things with it, but now I really need help.

I have this scenario:

I invoke a Java Rest WS using the following url:

```
http://192.168.3.41:8021/com.search.ws.module.ModuleSearch/getResults/jsonp?xmlQuery=%3C?xml%20version%3D'1.0'%20encoding%3D'UTF-8'?%3E%3Cquery%20ids%3D%2216535%22%3E%3CmatchWord%3Ehave%3C/matchWord%3E%3CfullText%3E%3C![CDATA[]]%3E%3C/fullText%3E%3CquotedText%3E%3C!...
```

But for this I had to use a Java util class to replace some special chars in the xml parameter, because the original xml is something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><query ids="16914"><matchWord>avoir</matchWord><fullText><![CDATA[]]></fullText><quotedText><![CDATA[]]></quotedText><sensitivity></sensitivity><operator>AND</operator><offsetCooc>0</offsetCooc><cooc></cooc><collection>0</collection><searchOn>all</searchOn><nbResultDisplay>10</nbResultDisplay><nbResultatsParAspect>...
```

Now, I've been asked to create a PHP page in which I can set the XML as input and request it to the REST WS using a submit button. I made an approach but not seems to be working, here I paste my code:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == "Submit") 
  {
    $crudXmlQuery = $_POST['inputXml'];
    echo $crudXmlQuery;
    echo "=================================================";
    $xml = str_replace("%", "%25", $crudXmlQuery);
    $xml = str_replace("&", "%26", $crudXmlQuery);
    $xml = str_replace("=", "%3D", $crudXmlQuery);
    echo $xml;
    //$ch = curl_init($url);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'inputXml='.$xml);
    //$info = curl_exec ($ch);
    //curl_close ($ch);
  }
?>
<form action="sampleIndex.php" method="post">
    Please insert your XML Query
    <input type='text' name='inputXml' value='<?=$crudXmlQuery?>'/>

    <input type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

I commented the part of the cURL since it was giving me some problems, I'm not sure how to handle this requirement yet, if somebody could help me please, I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'inputXml='.$xml);
```

this is not going to work, you shoud url encode $xml first. (using urlencode function)

The other part  - not sure what exactly not working there :) But I do not see you taking the value of input field anywhere in your code:

```
$crudXmlQuery = $_POST['inputXml'];
```

Comment: yes, I missed that line when copy-paste from my editor, but I am taking the value as you mentioned, but when I execute an "echo of this" it shows me strange characters instead the xml I put in the textfield.

Comment: can you copy paste the strange characters?

Comment: These are the characters printed when I execute an echo: avoirAND00all10580date0082.122.169.2440false3.0.51tcbet30]IND

Comment: I solved the problem, sorry, I'm still very dummy in php. Thanks for your response, it helped me to find mi mistakes. Thanks!